# How to launch a Chromium app from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, chromium

I've installed the text editor [Text](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text/mmfbcljfglbokpmkimbfghdkjmjhdgbg?hl=en) as a Chromium application. My usual approach to opening the editor is to use the menu options provided by the GUI.

How can I launch the editor using the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You can know the location of chrome app from "alacarte" menu.
Here is the example for launching "chrome dev editor"

[image]

[image]

Now then paste the command(location) on terminal

Answer (score 1):

To find out which command you need, just

1. navigate in chrome to `chrome://apps/`
2. right click on the desired app and select "Create Shortcuts"
3. Create a shortcut to the desktop and from there you can extract the command you will need to execute the app directly from the terminal

In my case I can do it by issuing the following command:

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --profile-directory=Default --app-id=mmfbcljfglbokpmkimbfghdkjmjhdgbg
```

But the id may vary from installation to installation.